# how to use PHPMyGraph5.0 to mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, graph

help please, i have been searching for months now. cant seem to use phpMyGraph5.0 to mysql php.
here's my code.

```
//Set content-type header
header("Content-type: image/png");

//Include phpMyGraph5.0.php
include_once('phpMyGraph5.0.php');
include('includes/dbconnect.php');

//Set config directives
$cfg['title'] = 'Example graph';
$cfg['width'] = 400;
$cfg['height'] = 200;

//Set data
$query="SELECT
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `table`.`datetime`) AS `date`,
        COUNT(DISTINCT `table`.`id`) AS `count`
        FROM `table`
        WHERE `table`.`datetime` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
        GROUP BY `date`
        ORDER BY `date`";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

if ($result) {
    $data=array(
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $month=$row["date"];
        $count=$row["count"];
        //add to data areray
        $dataArray[$month]=$count;
    }

);
 }
//Create phpMyGraph instance
$graph = new phpMyGraph();

//Parse
$graph->parseVerticalColumnGraph($data, $cfg);
?>
```

I need to be able to post a graph which compose of months and number of unique id per month. in the code the months is *$row["date"]* and number of unique id is *$row["count"].*

The graph should look like [this](http://postimg.org/image/6dwkulbyt/).

This is the original code. and i need my code to output like the array in this code.

```
<?php    
    //Set content-type header
    header("Content-type: image/png");

    //Include phpMyGraph5.0.php
    include_once('phpMyGraph5.0.php');

    //Set config directives
    $cfg['title'] = 'Example graph';
    $cfg['width'] = 400;
    $cfg['height'] = 200;

    //Set data

    //add to data areray
    $data = array 
    ( 
        'JAN'=>10, 
        'FEB'=>20, 
        'MAR'=>30, 
        'APR'=>100, 
        'MAY'=>20, 
        'JUNE'=>110, 
        'JULY'=>50,
        'AUG'=>50,
        'SEPT'=>50,
        'OCT'=>50,
        'NOV'=>50,
        'DEC'=>50,
    ); 
    //Create phpMyGraph instance
    $graph = new phpMyGraph();

    //Parse
    $graph->parseVerticalColumnGraph($data, $cfg);
?>
```

Comment: While formatting your code, I saw this line: $data=array( and it only closes after your while and outside your if?

Comment: oh yeah! my mistake it should be closed after while closes. but still does not work. its just an idea code that suppose to output the graph. thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you need to connect to the MySQL server and select the database before calling the *mysql_query()* function, is that rihgt?

That is really easy to do and you can do so with the following code:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Couldn\'t connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Database name
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('DatabaseName', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Error in mysql_select_db(): ' . mysql_error());
}
```

You can check out the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) for more. Hoping I helped you.

Edit:

after more details it looks like the problem is not connecting to the database but outputting the graph. The PHP pages outputs an image so you can't load it directly like other PHP pages, you should try to output the image generated from the PHP page in another page using the following code, just like in the PHPMyGraph examples:

```
<img src="pageThatOutputsTheGraph.php?data=someData" alt="Example code">
```

Comment: no that's not it. i updated the code. forgot to type the db connection. I want to produce a graph that is exactly like the one that the image that is link. dont know how to post array. will update post and add code for idea.

Comment: If I understood correclty you have an array like $array[$monthNo] = $count and you need to make a graph out of it, right? So you just need a PHPMyGraph example?

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? You fail to create the array or you copy the example and don't know what to do with it? Are you aware that **the page outputs an Image file and not HTML code**?

Comment: yes i am aware. i call the code as <img src="graph.php" alt="Your generated image" /> but it does not display the graph, only small image is displayed or broken image. my main problem is posting an array with the use of my data.

Comment: "$count" is the numbers of unique customers bought each month. $month  is a number ranging from 1 to 12 to post as month. for each $month there is $count.

Comment: Can you print_r the array you pass to PHPMyGraph and check that it's correct?